# MultiResourcePartitioning same speed as without partitioning in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Batch Job:

1. read from a txt file(50k records)
2. split it into 10 txt files(5k records each)
3. for each record in the txt create an xml file

The problem is that the same job without the splitting-partitioning(reading from original txt) takes the same amount of time

My configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- My beans -->   
    <bean id="task" class="com.example.model.MyModel" scope="prototype" />
    <bean id="noInputException" class="com.example.listener.NoWorkFoundStepExecutionListener"/>
    <bean id="idNameListener" class="com.example.listener.IdNameListener">
        <property name="mriw" ref="multiResourceItemWriter"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="txtsuffix" class="com.example.filename.TxtSuffix"/>
    <bean id="headerCallback" class="com.example.listener.HeaderCallBack"/>

    <bean id="partitioner" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner"
    scope="step">
    <property name="keyName" value="inputFile" />
    <property name="resources" value="file:../xml/xmlfiles/*.txt" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor" >
    </bean> 
      <!--<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
                <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
                <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        </bean>-->

    <!-- Batch Job declaration -->
    <batch:job id="txttoxml">
         <batch:step id="step1" next="step2master">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="fileReader" writer="TXTExporter" commit-interval="1000">
            </batch:chunk>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="noInputException"/>
                <batch:listener ref="idNameListener"/>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="step2master">
        <partition step="step2" partitioner="partitioner">
            <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </partition>
    </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="fileReaderstep2" writer="multiResourceItemWriter" commit-interval="1">
            </batch:chunk>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="noInputException"/>
                <batch:listener ref="idNameListener"/>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
   </batch:step>

    <!-- step1 writer -->
    <bean id="TXTExporter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:../xml/xmlfiles/xml"></property>
    <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemWriter"></property>
    <property name="itemCountLimitPerResource" value="5000"/>
    <property name="resourceSuffixCreator" ref="xmlsuffix"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="flatFileItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value="£"/>
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                <property name="names" value="ID,TYPE,NAME,DATESTARTED,DATEENDED" />
                </bean>
            </property>

        </bean>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fileReaderstep2"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
        autowire-candidate="false" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext[inputFile]}" />
        <property name="lineMapper" ref="lineMapper"/>        
    </bean>

    <bean id="multiResourceItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:../xml/P" />
        <property name="delegate" ref="XMLwriter"/>
        <property name="itemCountLimitPerResource" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="XMLwriter" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter"> 
        <property name="marshaller" ref="taskUnmarshaller" />
        <property name="rootTagName" value="Task" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskUnmarshaller"
     class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
        <property name="aliases">
            <map>
                <entry key="Task"
                value="com.example.model.MyModel" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>


  <!-- txt format -->
  <bean id="fileReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="lineMapper" ref="lineMapper"/>
        <property name="resource" value="file:../original.txt"/>
        <property name="strict" value="false"/>
        <!-- <property name="linesToSkip" value="1"/> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="lineMapper"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
        <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="fieldSetMapper"/>
        <property name="lineTokenizer" ref="lineTokenizer"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="lineTokenizer"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
        <property name="delimiter" value="£"/>
        <property name="names" value="ID,TYPE,NAME,DATESTARTED,DATEENDED"/>
        <property name="strict" value="false"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fieldSetMapper"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
        <property name="targetType" value="com.example.model.MyModel"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Is there any way to increase performance?

Comment: Your configuration is using the SycTaskExecutor.  This means that the partitions are executing one at a time (instead of in parallel).  I notice that the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is commented out.  Have you tried it with that?

Comment: When I use the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, job crushes after processing the first txt, I get:Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step.Should I add the configuration of transactionManager and JobRepository?

Comment: One small issue I see that may be your issue with the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor…Make the readers step scoped.  Right now they are singleton and the FlatFileItemReader is not thread safe.  If they are step scoped, each partition (since it's a full step instance) should get it's own instance.

Comment: The reader of the partitioned step(fileReaderstep2) is already step scoped

Comment: Then I'd need to see the exception that the unsuccessful step returned.  In either case, you won't get any better performance with the SyncTaskExecutor.

Comment: You are right about the SyncTaskExecutor.This is the errortrace when using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor: http://pastebin.com/pPcc2JkK

Comment: It looks like one of the partitions couldn't create the output file (based on the AccessDenied at line 86 of your stack trace)…Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Hey, have you been able to resolve the issue? I'm getting the same "unsuccessful step returned" exception using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

Comment: @dShringi yes but I don't remember how, it's been so long! Maybe check again scopes of readers/writers and follow the errortrace from the beginning not just the `unsuccessful step returned` because it usually spits an exception and other threads continue normally so in the end you get this abstract exception. That's all I remember :(